# Rails how to use a select list for a boolean field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am running on Rails 5.1.4 and having issues with using a select tag for a boolean field. Here's my form:

```
= f.select :insurance_authorization_required, options_for_select([["Yes", true], ["No", false]]), { :prompt => 'Select One'} , { :class => 'dropdown' }
```

I also validate the field's presence:

```
validates :insurance_authorization_required, presence: true
```

Selecting `Yes` saves the field properly as true, however if I select `No`, I get an error saying `insurance_authorization_required can't be blank`. I've tried to use `0` and `1` instead:

```
= f.select :insurance_authorization_required, options_for_select([["Yes", 1], ["No", 0]]), { :prompt => 'Select One'} , { :class => 'dropdown' }
```

But this gives the same result: Selecting "Yes" saves as `true` and "No" throws an error.

I've also tried to cast the field in my model:

```
def insurance_authorization_required=(val)
  if val.is_a?(TrueClass) || val.is_a?(FalseClass)
    super(val)
  else
    super(val == 'true' || val == '1')
  end
end
```

This didn't solve it either. I still get the blank error when selecting "No".

I saw multiple other questions like this one with the accepted answer saying using `true` and `false` as my select option's value would work, but why is it not working for me? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rails, **false** is considered **blank**. You can try on your rails console:

[image]

You should remove the presence validation, and set the field to default to false. Or, since it's a boolean, consider **true** as true, and false or nil as false.

Comment: Thank you! I did have the field default to `false`, but just wanted to check the presence to be sure. I completely forgot that `false` is considered blank, I guess I really need the weekend break. I guess I really need the weekend break...haha

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Woow, thanks. I had the same problem and couldn't figure out why it kept saying attribute can't be blank @Aleksandrus